TS6138 error for Usage of private properties of class in the `PassportStrategy` super()
I am defining a JwtStrategy class for using inside my NestJS module as below.
import { ConfigService } from '@/config/config.service';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { JwtPayLoad } from './interfaces/jwt-payload.interface';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: configService.auth.jwtSecret,
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: JwtPayLoad) {
    return { userId: payload.userId, username: payload.username };
  }
}


I am getting this TypeScript error.

| src/auth/jwt.strategy.ts:9:32 - error TS6138: Property 'configService' is declared but its value is never read.
| 9   constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {

I am not sure why the TypeScript does not understand that the usage of configService variable inside the super function of my constructor.
I don't want to simply import the JWTSECRET from the env file and want to keep my configuration module like this. The only solution I have already found is to change the private variable to protected which I am not sure if this is safe to do.

The reason you're getting this error is that by doing this you have also declared a variable on the class level that you're not using. This is what's happening under the hood:
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  // this is automatically declared in the constructor
  private readonly configService: ConfigService;

  constructor(configService: ConfigService) {
    // this is also automatically set by the constructor
    this.configService = configService;

    super({
      // using the local `configService` variable and not the one on the class level
      secretOrKey: configService.auth.jwtSecret,
      /* ... */
    });
  }
}

In order to fix the error you can remove declaration of the class level variable, as you never access it:
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  // get rid of the automatic class level variable
  constructor(configService: ConfigService) {
    super({
      secretOrKey: configService.auth.jwtSecret,
      /* ... */
    });
  }
}


Thanks for the answer, very clear example and edit.
The second solution is wrong and the first solution still is not as good as constructor(protected readonly configService: ConfigService) { which I already have.
The second solution is wrong because I am trying to access the class property which is not available inside the parent class (I am trying to access the variable inside the super() function.). Please let me know if I have any solution to still set the variable as private not protected or public.

Indeed, accessing this is disallowed before super() in TypeScript. I stand corrected. However, I do not see another solution to the problem.

Thank you again for your quick reply. I mark you answer as correct answer the final best workable solution for anyone who read us from the future is constructor(protected readonly configService: ConfigService) {super({...});}.
